# Installing hostapd via apt-get and dpkg results in different boot behaviour

Tags: apt, dpkg, hostapd

I am trying to set up a Wifi hotspot on Debian 7.6. After reading a few tutorials, I have managed to get the Wifi working by installing and configuring `hostapd`.

I need to install and configure this on many different machines, some with no internet access, thus, I downloaded the `deb` packages for hostapd and its dependencies from here:

http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main

and wrote a script to configure the network interfaces and what not.

The problem is, if I install the required packages (**libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.7-4_i386.deb**, **libnl-3-200_3.2.7-4_i386.deb** and **hostapd_1.0-3+deb7u2_i386.deb**) using `dpkg` rather than using `apt-get`, the machine hangs at boot, however the Wifi is up and running.

After manual install and configuration, running `service hostapd restart` hangs when it attempts to start the service. While the the terminal hangs at `[....] Starting advanced IEEE 802.11 management: hostapd.` the wifi becomes accessible and I can connect to it successfully. Terminating the hanging process by pressing `Ctrl+C` will kill the Wifi connection. It feels like `hostapd` is not started in a separate thread, and thus hangs.

I have compared the md5sum of manually downloaded packages and those found in **/var/cache/apt/archives** and the md5sums match up, so it must be config, yet the config I apply when install via `apt-get` and `dpkg` are identical.

I have read that `apt-get` uses `dpkg` to install the actual packages, so I have no idea how this happens with the same debs and same applied config. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm properly understanding this question. The package acts differently when you install via `apt` and `dpkg` how? And did you build your own custom debs? I'm not clear about that. "wrote a script to configure the network interfaces and what not". Is this part of the package?

Comment: @FaheemMitha When installing with `apt-get` the machines boots successfully and wifi is up. When installing with `dpkg`, the machines hangs on boot, but the wifi is up. I did not create customs debs, I downloaded the debs from the debian repo. Configuring network interfaces is not part of the package. (Adding `wlan0` `/etc/network/interfaces`, adding subnet to `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`, etc... )

Comment: If the debs are identical, I can see no reason for different behavior. When you install with `dpkg`, do you make sure the dependencies are satisfied. Do you run `apt-get -f install` afterwards, for example? Also, I'm missing the reason why using `dpkg` directly is necessary.

Comment: I need to install hostapd on machines without internet access, thus, pre-downloading the debs and installing using `dpkg` is my only option. The only two outstanding dependencies are **libnl-genl-3-200** and **libnl-3-200**, which I install with `dpkg` before installing hostapd. So the dependencies are met.

Comment: Hmm. Could this be a case of correlation instead of causation? When you said "no internet access" you presumably meant no wired or ethernet access? So, how do the machines that you are installing dpkg on differ from those that you are using apt on? Do the former not have ethernet while the former do? If so, could the ethernet connection be making a difference in how the wifi is behaving?

Comment: I see what you are saying, but as of yet I have only tried the two solutions on a single machine, with internet access. By saying I have to install the software on machines with no internet access simply provides reason behind manually installing the deb packages rather than using `apt-get`.

Comment: Oh, I see. I misunderstood, then. On the same machine, I can think of no reason you would see different behavior between using `apt-get` as opposed to `dpkg -i` directly.